# How to speed up e-mail sending in phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Actually I'm using PHPmailer for sending e-mails to my client's. I'm looking for solution, how to speedup mail sending by script. Actually my speed is 80 msg/ per minute. Is there any way to speedup sending?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk Mailing Performance Sending Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28117973/bulk-mailing-performance-sending-method)

Comment: Another good solution IMHO is to use an external service like Mailchimp, SendGrid, Mailgun or other.

Comment: Actually I'm using sendGrid with self hosted system based on phpmailer, but there is problem - it slow sending mails to SendGrid SMTP.

Comment: Use their API instead of their SMTP, it will be quicker ;)

Comment: I have no trouble sending over 10,000 messages/minute using PHPMailer over SMTP to a nearby mail server. See my answer on the question Veve linked to.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer will be slow, there isn't really a way around it. If you are sending the emails from your local mail server you can instead submit it to that locally and make the process almost instant. You can also read more at this (similar) question:
[Speed up PHPmailer with office 365 smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116362/speed-up-phpmailer-with-office-365-smtp)

Comment: It isn't true that PHPMailer will make it slow, and this should be a comment anyway.

Comment: Thank you, this was a simple and great solution. My website processes and jobs were timing out due to 15 second smtp send times though office 365, by setting up my vps smtp relay instead its instant now.